# form-data is successfully uploaded in first-run, but when form activity is recreated it show anolmous behavior

Tags: android

android app: i am having a form in my first activity, whose user-input data is stored using shared preferences, and later is synced to database in third activity && intent to first activity is called from third activity.

form-data is successfully uploaded in first-run, but when form(first) activity is recreated (via intent from last activity) old data of form is submitted instead of new data entered by user.

modified data is submitted only once when i restart-application.

can anyone guide me. where i am going wrong..

**snapshot of form(first-activity)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved ..
by changing the mode of shared_preference from MODE_PRIVATE to MODE_MULTI_PROCESS

Actually , sharedpreference were being updated via one process.
and synced via different process.

note : it is depreciated for latest api, refer github for alternate methods to implement the same.